# Fuel Level Sensor Safety

Tags: sensor, safety, industrial, fuel-gauge

I'm looking up fuel level sensor manufacturers (Omnicomm, Technoton etc) and noticed that a lot of them offer capacitive fuel sensors for all types of fuel. However, based on my understanding, capacitive fuel sensing involves electronics and fuel is highly flammable, the tiniest spark could cause an explosion. I tried to look up explanations for this but couldn't find something satisfactory (is galvanic isolation enough?).

I was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction, and if capacitive sensing really is safe for fuel tank level sensing, which sensors do you suggest for sensing petrol level at a filling station (not vehicles).

Please direct me to some industry standards/safety or regulations document for reference, thank you so much for your help!

If you require any more information, I'm ready to provide it.

Comment: Fuel won't ignite unless you make a hole in your tank to let the fresh air in. And capacitive coupling has nothing to do with sparks.

Comment: If the thought of a capacitive sensor near your gas tank makes you nervous, then I suggest you not take a look at how the sending unit on most cars works - you'd find that downright **frightening.**

Comment: Since you are asking specifically about gas in the tanks at a filling station, I'll tell you what my calculus teacher told the guy who asked her how to calculate the levels for a marking on a measuring stick for a filling station tank:  Start with an empty tank.  Fill known quantities of fuel into the tank.  Poke your stick in and mark it according to the measured level and the known filled volume.  Tanks are never perfectly level, nor are they really the nominal size.  That's why the measuring sticks were invented in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are Ex standards. The sensor itself has to be Ex version approved. The main point is to use such power supply and signal evaluation that does not produce spark in case of short circuit or malfunction - so this is so called Ex barrier. This is a device that separates non-ex zone and ex zone. All signals in ex zone are fed through this barrier, also the wiring has to be ex version, usually the cables are blue coloured.

[image]